# Keyboard backlight is not working in Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina

MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) with MAC OS Catalina 10.15. The keyboard backlight is not turning on. Is there a button in software or in hardware which I can use to turn-on the backlight manually

How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: check if resetting SMC works http://osxdaily.com/2010/03/24/when-and-how-to-reset-your-mac-system-management-controller-smc/. Then if the issue is still not resolved check PRAM settings http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/15/reset-pram-mac/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adjust the keyboard brightness manually in Macbook Pro by customizing the Keyboard control strip to have the keys related to Keyboard brightness as mentioned below. (F5, F6, etc function keys did not work for me)

`Apple logo -> System preferences -> Keyboard -> Customize Control Strip ->` Drag and drop Keyboard brightness button to the touch bar as shown in the image below

[image]

Then use this to manually adjust the keyboard backlight brightness